# What happens in memory when the Activity is destroyed while its AsyncTask is running?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, garbage-collection

I've been playing around with an app I created.

1. Activity A(1st Activity) has a button that executes an AsyncTask.  This AsyncTask's  doInBackground() performs calculations on selected values in Activity A, and its  onPostExecute() starts Activity B.
2. I click the button, then before Activity B can be started I press back to destroy Activity A.
3. The app closes, then relaunches with Activity B populated with calculations from my AsyncTask.

[this awesome blog](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/activitys-threads-memory-leaks.html) explains memory leaks with Threads when the screen is rotated, and I'm applying those lessons here with my AsyncTask and back button press. However, I'm still a little confused.

1. Pressing back on an Activity destroys it.
2. My asynctask is running on an activity that was destroyed, should throw a NPE since it's accessing list elements inside that activity.
3. But it didn't.  What does destroyed really mean then?  I thought it meant that the Activity A reference and its view hierarchy would be set to null to allow the garbage collector to sweep it up sometime and recycle the memory.  The blog states it didn't, hence the memory leak.

So wait, Activity A didn't get destroyed?  But I saw it disappear...

This is a conceptual question rather than a code question so far, but as requested:

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<ArrayList<Train>, Void, Void> {

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // Runs on the UI thread before doInBackground
        spinWait.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
        waitMsg.setText("Calculating Schedules....");

        spinWait.bringToFront();
        waitMsg.bringToFront();
    }


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(ArrayList<Train>... lolTrains) {

        try {
            calcSchedules(lolTrains[0]);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("DEBUG", "Calculating schedules failed, " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {
        // This method is executed in the UIThread
        spinWait.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        waitMsg.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        // if schedules is empty, show error dialog
        if (schedules.size() == 0) {
            // show msg, etc
        } else {
            Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), ResultsActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("results", schedules);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    }
}

public void MethodInActivityA(View v) {
    new MyAsyncTask().execute(memberVarInActivityA);
}
```

Comment: Activity destruction is an Android concept. It means that activity instance will never be displayed to the user again and thus is left to die eventually at the mercy of the GC, it does not happen immediately

Comment: @Machinarius: So the sequence of events was Activity A disappears but memory still exists because AsyncTask references it, then Activity B appears, then Activity A memory gets garbage collected since AsyncTask is done with Activity A?

Comment: Something similar, the problem is that your callback fired on activity A, meaning data is wasted on the best case scenario and your application crashes because you try to update invalid ui on the worst one.

Comment: can you please clarify what you mean by "best and worst case scenarios"?  I don't think my app crashed because I don't get the "Unfortunately, appname has stopped" error dialog.

Comment: If you don't use the data from the thread to update your UI then everything will mostly go your way -it will just be a memory leak- merrily camouflaging the problem. If you do, you might get exceptions because you tried to update the UI of a destroyed activity.

Comment: actually, that's my question exactly.  I thought the member variable of Activity A(the list I pass into asynctask) would be destroyed(null) since its activity is destroyed.  But it isn't because no NPE was thrown, and instead Activity B, whose results are based on the list in Activity A, shows perfectly.  I think the explanation is Activity A here has its view destroyed but not anything else.  If its vars were destroyed(set to null) too, I would have gotten an NPE.

Answer (score 1):

When you destroyed your activity, you did not destroy you AsyncTask (which is basically kind of a `Thread`), to do that try

```
asyncTask.cancel(true);
```

on your `onDestroy();` method

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

On your `onPostExecute()`, When start new activity call `finsih()` followed by `startActivity(i)`. This `finish()` internally call `onDestroy`. Here you need to clear Asynctask manually because Asynctask is inner class of your Activity. Even activity was destroyed this inner class holds the reference of activity. You need manually clear the reference by `asyncTask.cancel()`.